# Android Multipart Form File upload in Marshmallow

Tags: android, file-upload, okhttp

I'm trying to upload a file to the server using multipart form.
Since API 23 Android has deprecated the Apache HTTP library.

I switched to using OkHttp to do my file uploads like so:

```
        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart(name, fileName, requestBodyPart)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();
```

And the `requestBodyPart` is:

```
        requestBodyPart = new RequestBody() {
            @Override
            public MediaType contentType() {
                return MediaType.parse(contentType);
            }

            @Override
            public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
                try {
                    if (sink.writeAll(Okio.source(inputStream)) == 0) {
                        throw new IOException("Empty File!");
                    }
                } finally {
                    MiscUtils.closeCloseable(inputStream);
                }
            }
        };
```

However, it seems like OkHttp is not that great when it comes to file uploads. Lots of timeouts and seems to be creating several layers of abstractions (sources and sinks) and has this AsyncTimeout that fires while the file data is still being written over the socket.

Are there any recommendations for doing Multipart File Uploads from Android that work with API 23 onwards. I know I can include the HTTP legacy library but since it was removed I would prefer not to do that. Or is there a way I can improve the performance of OkHttp?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
String name = ...
File file = ...
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse(...)
OkHttpClient httpClient = ...
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(new MultipartBuilder().type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                                    .addFormDataPart(name,
                                                     file.getName(),
                                                     RequestBody.create(mediaType, file))
                                    .build())
        .build();
try {
    Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes I'm using exactly that. The problem is that it is not performant with files that are slightly large or on slow networks where the timeout happens while the file is being written.

Comment: Timeout should not occur till any data gets written to socket. You could configure timeouts by using 
`OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
httpClient.setConnectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
httpClient.setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: I actually have set it to more than 3 minutes right now. What happens is that the last bytes of a large file have still not transferred over to the socket the AsyncTimeout kicks in (I guess because the underlying socket is buffering some of the data). The AsyncTimeout doesn't work on the socket but on the Application with a sleep() and it fires before the response comes back from the server, even though the socket it self has not timed out.